# How do I Host a Virtual Machine with the GUI Accessible on Docker?

Tags: virtual-machine, docker

Imagine the following scenario, I have a network at my house with five computers on it.  One of them I've set-up to be a server, so it is permanently on and accessible from the rest of the network.  I would like to host some docker images on it but I don't just want a computer I can SSH into.  What I would really want is a computer that I can actually view on another computer with a GUI.

Unfortunately, I'm not the only one in the house and so there are times at which the computer needs to be accessible to multiple people, eliminating things like RDPing into the main server and using something like VirtualBox.  What other options are available to me that allow me to host multiple docker OS' with a GUI available to the outside world?

It's easy to set-up this system for access via SSH, but I've never seen any solutions that allow me to get their desktop GUI.

Comment: What OS's are you using? Are they windows or mac?

Comment: @LPChip The server is currently running Windows Server, but will be hosting various server OS', Windows/Mac/Linux.

Comment: Windows Server has something called Terminal Services, which allows concurrent RDP sessions. Why is that not desired?

Comment: Main issue I have with that @LPChip is that the reason I'm setting this up is mostly to give children the ability to use these VMs.  It's why I went for Docker because it is moderately difficult to break out of the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker doesn't run an OS, it runs an application. If you would like to run a complete OS, you need virtualization, not containerization.

From what I can understand, what you'd like is a computer that runs several virtual machines, all of which could be accessed remotely. This can be accomplished using VirtualBox or VmWare (other virtualization solutions might be able to do it too, but I don't know them).

Since you mentioned VirtualBox in your question, I'll focus on that. VirtualBox has an [entire documentation page](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html) on how to set up RDP access to a virtual machine, including how to start the VM in headless mode so that it doesn't open a window on the server. Using this, you RDP directly onto the guest, not into the main host, so it is still relatively difficult to escape the VM.